# Bulk remove Wordpress admin columns for all post types

Tags: php, wordpress

I use this filter to remove / add columns in Wordpress "pages" type admin columns:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-page_columns', 'my_admin_remove_columns', 10, 1 );
```

Is there a way to use it in a "wild card" style to add / remove columns to all existing post types together without specifying each one in a separate filter?